# Whats the difference between 'Eventual Distributed Programming' and 'Functional Programming'

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, eventual-consistency

I read the book "How Javascript Works" by Douglas Crockford. He concludes the book by writing

> I think it should be obvious by now that the next paradigm is Distributed Eventual Programming. This is not a new idea. It goes back at least to the discovery of the Actor Model (1973) - (location 1608).

I do not understand how the Distributed Eventual Programming paradigm differs from the functional programming paradigm. Are they overlapping concepts?

Comment: i too would like clarification, especially regarding his comment that javascript was "specifically created to do Distributed Eventual Programming". my guess is thats a reference to event listeners in the early day. but how is it distributed?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the control flow. In a very much simplified view:

- In imperative programming, the order of your program's statements determines the control flow: Statements are executed one after another in the order you write them - except for explicit control flow statements (if/else, for, while, etc.).
- In functional programming, the nesting of function calls determines the control flow: If a function *f* relies on the result of function *g*, *f* will be executed after *g*, no matter in which order they appear in your source code.
- In an eventual programming model, functions are executed in the order they appear in a queue. If your function *f* enqueues functions *g* and *h*, then *g* and *h* will be executed in the order they appear in the queue. The queueing order does not necessarily need to be the order *g* and *h* appear in your source code; it might depend on some outside event like a timeout or a keypress.

The eventual model works with both the imperative and the functional paradigm - as shown in JavaScript, which lets you write both imperative and functional code. Operating systems themselves have been working with event queues since the early days of Unix, and even the very first Windows GUI (atop a single-process DOS) had an event queue. What I suppose Crockford referred to is having an event queue as a fundamental part of your program runtime system, not the operating system; i.e., that the control flow of a single program is fundamentally determined by its event queue instead of the control flow that you construct via ordering statements (imperative paradigm) or nesting function calls (functional paradigm).

What about the distributed part? Eventual programming can be single-threaded, as in any JS runtime: There is one thread that polls the event queue and executes the enqueued functions one after another. Under the hood, there typically is some mechanism that enqueues events generated outside of your program, such as mouse clicks or incoming requests over the network. Such a mechanism may be interrupts at the hardware-level, or services of the operating system at higher levels (like Node's V8 runtime or any browser runtime).

*Distributed* now means that you can have multiple eventual programs that communicate via messages (also called the *Actor Model*). It doesn't matter if the event queues are physically distributed across multiple machines, or if they are simply running in different processes locally (your JS runtime has a separate event queue for each browser tab or window).

So, functional programming and distributed eventual programming are different but complementary paradigms. I understand Crockford saying that we should use eventual programming and asynchronous message passing to orchestrate computation that is highly interactive and that involves services hosted on the internet, instead of running non-eventual (i.e., sequential and thus blocking) programs that communicate via synchronous remote procedure calls.